# Sending blog posts via email to groups based on wordpress categories

Tags: php, wordpress, api, mailchimp

When I post an article in a wordpress blog and assign it to several categories, is there a simple way to send the full post to specific groups within a list inside mailchimp? For example, when I post an article and assign it to categories A,B and C...I want to automate a process to take the content of that blog post and send it via email to groups A, B and C within a single list in mailchimp.

I tried using the RSS to Email campaign within mailchimp, but that doesn't allow me to automatically send to dynamic groups based on categories chosen for the blog post.

I am certainly open to plugins that would achieve my goal. Actually, a well supported plugin would be my preference.

Comment: I think you are seeking a Wordpress addin solution, rather than a programming solution.  If you can clarify what you are asking to make it on-topic for this site, e.g. a developer/code problem, that would improve your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `publish_post` action to achieve what you want.
`add_action( 'publish_post', 'send_email_after_post_published', 10, 2 );`

Now, create the function which will handle the email functionality

```
function send_email_after_post_published($ID, $post){
    if($post->post_type==='post'){
        $categories=get_the_category( $post->ID );
        //now you can send email according to the category 
    }
}
```

See this for more details
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post

Comment: So I guess I would need to custom program something using the publish_post and utilize the mailchimp api. However with the publish_post, would it send email again if I update a post (fix a spelling, change a link, etc.)?

Comment: No, it won't. `publish_post` is triggered after a post is published. You should hook `edit_post` if you need it in update. `save_post` works for both though.